# Set QVBoxLayout in full size in main window without spacing or border

Tags: c++, qt

I am making media player and have QLabel in which will be displaying video and that label inserted in QVBoxLayout. QVBoxLayout not in full size and it have spaces between QVBoxLayout and edge of main window. I want that it will be like for example in VLC media player.

How it looks like now:
[![image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yizsU.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1088</width>
    <height>703</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Cube Player</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeConstraint">
       <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="wFull" native="true">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_6">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>9</number>
         </property>
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>5</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDuration">
           <property name="text">
            <string>--:--</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QSlider" name="slDuration">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QSlider::groove:horizontal {
border: 1px solid #999999;
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #B1B1B1, stop:1 #c4c4c4);
height: 7px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #8e1818, stop: 1 #fc8888);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #fc8888, stop: 1 #cc0404);
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
border: 1px solid #777;
width: 13px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 4px;
}
</string>
           </property>
           <property name="maximum">
            <number>10000</number>
           </property>
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="QLabel" name="lblVideoTime">
           <property name="text">
            <string>--:--</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnMute">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QSlider" name="slSound">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">QSlider::groove:horizontal {
border: 1px solid #999999;
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #B1B1B1, stop:1 #c4c4c4);
height: 7px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0,    x2: 0, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #8e1818, stop: 1 #fc8888);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.2, x2: 1, y2: 1,
    stop: 0 #fc8888, stop: 1 #cc0404);
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #777;
height: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #eee, stop:1 #ccc);
border: 1px solid #777;
width: 13px;
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover {
background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1,
    stop:0 #fff, stop:1 #ddd);
border: 1px solid #444;
border-radius: 4px;
}
</string>
             </property>
             <property name="maximum">
              <number>100</number>
             </property>
             <property name="value">
              <number>50</number>
             </property>
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnFullScreen">
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="shortcut">
              <string>Esc</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QWidget" name="mainButtons" native="true">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>3</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
         <property name="spacing">
          <number>3</number>
         </property>
         <item>
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnStop">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
             <horstretch>0</horstretch>
             <verstretch>0</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="Line" name="line">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPrev">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPlay">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
             <property name="shortcut">
              <string>Space</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnNext">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
         <item>
          <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
           <property name="orientation">
            <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnEqualizer">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string/>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1088</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuMedia">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Media</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen_file"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuMedia"/>
  </widget>
  <action name="aOpenFile">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open file</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionOpen_file">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open file</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share your .ui ...

Comment: Are you sure the spacing is due to the `QVBoxLayout` and not the `QGridLayout` that it's in?

Comment: G.M. Thanks that was answer to my problem. I had to set margins to zero in QGridLayout